# How to find a constrain slack in a opl cplex?

Tags: cplex, slack, opl

I ve a MIP model and I wanna know which constrains are active.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

let me give you a small example:

```
dvar float+ Gas;
dvar float+ Chloride;


maximize
  40 * Gas + 50 * Chloride;
subject to {
 ctMaxTotal:     
Gas + Chloride <= 50;
  ctMaxTotal2:    
3 * Gas + 4 * Chloride <= 180;
  ctMaxChloride:  
Chloride <= 40;
}

float slackCtMaxTotal=slack(ctMaxTotal);
float slackCtMaxTotal2=slack(ctMaxTotal2);
float slackCtMaxChloride=slack(ctMaxChloride);

execute
{
writeln("slack1= ",slackCtMaxTotal);
writeln("slack2= ",slackCtMaxTotal2);
writeln("slack3= ",slackCtMaxChloride);
}
```